# In PHP, how to check how much memory a certain loop is using

Tags: php, benchmarking

I'm currently making a PHP timer that checks how much time a certain way of doing something takes compared to another thing that accomplishes the same, basically benchmarking.

Now, I would also like to make this tool be able to tell how much memory that specific way of doing it is taking up.

So, for more info, I'm using microtime to check the start time, do 2000 thousand loops on that code and then do another microtime with some math to check how much time it took, so what I would like to do is, outside the microtime scope, also check for memory usage.

This is my current code:

```
// Set the amount of loops to do, default is 2000
$loops = 2000;
$start_time = microtime(true); // Start the timer

for($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
    // Code to test
}

$total_time = microtime(true) - $start_time; // Stop the timer, and figure out the total

ob_end_flush();   // Enable output again
echo $total_time; // Echo the timer's result
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `memory_get_usage` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) when you think the process is at its peak.

Or you could also just call it occasionally and record whatever was the highest value... or as you please.

But this is within a process. Are you talking about a PHP process "A" checking another PHP process' memory usage?

If so:

```
$myPID = getmypid();
$stats = explode("\n", shell_exec('pmap $(pgrep php) | grep \'total\\|\\:\''));
for ($i = 0; $i < count($stats); $i += 2) {
    if (strpos($stats[$i], "$myPID") === false) {
        preg_match('/\d+/', $stats[$i+1], $preRes);
        $res = $preRes[0];
    }
}
//if $res has a value, that value is the kilobytes of memory being used by the other PHP process
```

This solution has a problem: if you have more than 2 php processes running total, you can't guarantee that you will be getting the right process.

To solve this, run first the other process, obtain its PID and then pass it as argument to this process. If you have the process' PID you want to check, you could just do this:

```
$stats = explode("\n", shell_exec('pmap $(pgrep php) | grep \'total\\|\\:\''));
for ($i = 0; $i < count($stats); $i += 2) {
    if (strpos($stats[$i], "$otherPID") === 0) {
        preg_match('/\d+/', $stats[$i+1], $preRes);
        $res = $preRes[0];
    }
}
//$res contains the result you want in kilobytes
```

You could check the memory for all processes that are not you, too:

```
$myPID = getmypid();
$stats = explode("\n", shell_exec('pmap $(pgrep php) | grep \'total\\|\\:\''));
for ($i = 0; $i < count($stats) - 1; $i += 2) {
    if (strpos($stats[$i], "$myPID") === false) {
        preg_match('/\d+/', $stats[$i+1], $preRes);
        $res[] = $preRes[0];
    }
}
```

So to get the maximum memory usage, just keep a $max variable and keep checking against it.

Comment: I updated the question with my code, yes I'm talking about process A checking process B's memory usage.

Comment: Does it have to be done using PHP? If yes, will it run on a Linux OS or under Windows?

Comment: Yes it has to be PHP, it's not gonna run on Windows, it's gonna run on UNIX, and it's not gonna run on a Mac OS X server. That's what I know.

Comment: Cool, looking forward to a working script. If the solution isn't easy, I might just check the memory usage every 200 loops and just do some math on that. Really appreciate you helping me. :)

Comment: I had too look up for something! I usually skip this questions and just wait for someone else to answer them hehhee. I hope this works for what you need... sorry for not providing a perfect solution.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot. :) As you can probably guess, I'm still kind of a newbie. :P Once again, I appreaciate your help a lot (been couple of days trying to figure it out, lol).

Comment: From the original code it doesn't look like the profiler is using two separate OS processes, so this (while awesome) is maybe overkill?

Comment: It may be overkill... If it is, I'm only gonna use it on an advanced version of this script, so overkill is not overkill. ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you're on at least 5.2, `memory_get_peak_usage()` should work just fine.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php

You can call it once prior to the loop to get an idea of your baseline up to that point, then again afterward to see what peak was during loop execution.

Modifying your code...

```
// Set the amount of loops to do, default is 2000
$loops = 2000;
$base_mem = memory_get_peak_usage();
$start_time = microtime(true); // Start the timer

for($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
    // Code to test
}
$end_time = microtime(true);  // Stop the timer
$extra_mem = memory_get_peak_usage();

// figure out the totals
$total_time = $end_time - $start_time;
$total_mem = $extra_mem - $base_mem;

ob_end_flush();   // Enable output again
echo "Total Time: $total_time\n";
echo "Total Mem Above Basline: $total_mem bytes\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes I might just do this if the solution isn't a simple one. :)